# Specified port 3306 is already in use when installing MySQL 5.6

Tags: mysql

When I try to install MySQL 5.6 and it tells me that the specified port 3306 is already in use.

I already uninstalled my previous MySQL which is version 5.1 already and I do not have any idea to check which program is using the port.

Can somebody please post a step by step guide?

Comment: when you install `MySQL 5.6`, you can change the port into 3307.

Comment: Open task manager and look for `mysqld` process

Comment: But does it create problem when I try to compile the whole project? As in will it crash? Because this is group work and I scared it crash

Comment: I do not have anything related to MySQL running except the installer

Comment: did you actually _stop_ the old process before you removed MySQL?

Comment: How to stop? I just simply remove from control panel

Comment: You can run `netstat -tulpn` to see what process is listening on 3306.

Comment: most servers that run MySQL don't have control panels... ;-)

Comment: What is netstat -tulpn? And where do I run it? Sorry because I never touched all these things before

Comment: @Carol this question is actually off topic here.  This site is for _programming questions_, not server admin.

Comment: Oh I fixed it already by stopping the service in MyComputer. Thanks a lot and sorry for posting at the wrong place because I have no idea where to ask

Answer (score 0):

First of all uninstall  the previous version of mysql... in most of the cases it works. If it doesn't , open Run (win+R) and type "resmon.exe" .A window will be opened, now click on Listening ports .Now you can see port "3306" as mysqld.exe. Now, remember   the PID of the mysqld.exe. Now, open cmd (as administrator) and type 
taskkill /F /PID 3306 (if your PID is 3306) .... 
 That's it now you can reinstall mysql again with 3306 port